# Compile preprocessor output using gcc

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I've generated a preprocessor out using the `-E`command.

Is it possible to compile exactly that generated file using `gcc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just save the output as a C or C++ file (or whatever the input was).

That's exactly what GCC does, schematically speaking: preprocess, then compile.

Comment: Unfortunately I get undefined references. Compiling the files directly works pretty fine.

Comment: Undefined references is a link-time error, not compile-time. What are you compiling (C? C++? something else?) and what exact steps are you taking?

Comment: Mea culpa. I was using gcc instead of using g++ for compiling and linking c++.